# JSON Response from laravel

Tags: json, laravel, response

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong in my implementation.

---

[Edit] - Because I wasn't clear. I'd like to have the modal respond to the contact form's successful execution. I'd like the modal to appear to the user with an Okay button (I can code that later).

#### Route

```
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@getContact');
Route::post('contact', 'PagesController@postContact');
```

#### View

```
{{ Form::open(array('id' => 'form-contact', 'data-parsley-validate' => '')) }}
...
form inputs
...
{{ Form::close() }}

<div id="flash-overlay-modal" class="modal fade hide {{ $modalClass or '' }}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ $title }}</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Controller

```
public function postContact(Request $request)
{
... Some logic
Mail::to($data['email'])->queue(new ContactForm($data));
              Redis::incr('send.contact');

              //Redirect to contact page
              // return redirect()->back()->with('success', true)->with('message','Your message was successfully sent. Ill be in touch soon');
              $msg = array(
                  'status' => 'success',
                  'msg' => 'Message sent successfully',
              );
              // return response()->json($msg); 
              return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'payload' => View::make('pages.contact', $msg)));
```

#### JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form-contact').on(submit, function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formEl = $(this);
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var company = $('#company').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var subject = $('#subject').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        var datastring = {
            name: name,
            company: company,
            email: email,
            subject: subject,
            message: message
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: './contact',
            data: dataString,
            accept: {
                javascript: 'application/javascript'
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // notice that we are expecting a json array with success = true and a payload
                    $('#masterModal').empty().append(data.payload).modal('show');
                } else {
                    // for debugging    
                    alert(data);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

#### Response

```
{
"success": true,
"payload": {}
}
```

I'm getting a JSON response from the controller, but it isn't activating the modal as expected. I searched several places for assistance and was unable to find any. Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In your url field of `ajax` remove the dot and try again

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @ViniciusLuiz -  yes I'm using bootstrap...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller's response instead of what you currently have for `payload`:

```
'payload' => View::make('pages.contact', $msg)->render()
```

Found here (https://laravel.io/forum/08-23-2014-return-view-in-json)

Comment: Will try this now.

Comment: I tried this, but it return the full page in json. Any ideas what next? @hollings

Comment: If you're trying to append `data.payload` to the modal, I would suggest putting your modal content into its own view, and returning that view in your payload.

Comment: I did this:

return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'payload' => View::make('partials._modal', $data)->render()));

and it returned another JSON.

Comment: just saw your recent edit:

You have `.modal()`, which only initializes the modal. `.modal('show')` will initialize _and_ show the modal.

Comment: I'm still getting a JSON response. Page is reloading and then displaying some json data.